# I want to show value into text box auomtically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check attchment i want to show customer name when open the dialog box
This is my wiki page in this wiki page i have one list view web part when i click on any item that time i show the dialog model this dialog i have on customer text box i want show select customer name into this textbox.
[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your question in detail as it quite difficult to understand your question with that screenshot.

Comment: http://www.qdoscc.com/blog/how-automatically-retrieve-current-username-infopath-sharepoint-list-form

Comment: Please read the question i edit my question. Thanks

Comment: how are you binding item link to open new popup ? can you paste your code in question...ideally it should be done using jquery...